# Get dd/mm/yyyy in daterangepicker in different inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, daterangepicker

i got this code

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
 <fieldset>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label clear" for="reservation" style="display:block; float:none;">Reservation dates:</label>
    <div class="controls" style="margin:0!important">
     <div class="input-prepend">
       <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" name="reservation" id="reservation" value="03/18/2013 - 03/23/2013" size="20" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
  </div>
 </fieldset>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reservation').daterangepicker();
}); 
</script>
```

and i need to get in different inputs the value
How can i do this?

i'm ussing bootstrap

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Dan Grossman's daterangepicker for twitter bootstrap. 
Is that correct?

http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/

First question is: what are you actually intending to do? 
Do you want to show a separate input for the start, 
and a separate from the end? And if so, what is the reason why?
Is it because those are the values you need to submit to the server?

Second question: are you familiar with the demos on Dan Grossman's site, 
near the bottom of his original post, and the demos on his github page?

http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/
https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/blob/master/examples.html

Note how he provides a way to access the start and end date values.

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(
    {
        ranges: {
            'Today': ['today', 'today'],
            'Yesterday': ['yesterday', 'yesterday'],
            'Last 7 Days': [Date.today().add({ days: -6 }), 'today'],
            'Last 30 Days': [Date.today().add({ days: -29 }), 'today'],
            'This Month': [Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth(), Date.today().moveToLastDayOfMonth()],
            'Last Month': [Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth().add({ months: -1 }), Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth().add({ days: -1 })]
        }
    },
    function(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.toString('MMMM d, yyyy') + ' - ' + end.toString('MMMM d, yyyy'));
    }
);
```

If you have access to `start` and `end`, you should be able to put those values in separate inputs, if that is what you want to do.